# Object doesn't work inside an if statement

Tags: oop, animation, processing

I'm trying to make a version of pong that is single player. When the player hits the wall the wall shrinks. If the player misses the ball the becomes a bullet and adds another ball to the game. There is more to the game but I can't get past this part. I defined a class with my ball, bullet, and new ball object. If I call newBall() at the beginning of draw() it will work. But if I put it inside my if statement (the new ball appears IF the player misses), it doesn't show.I know the if statement is correct because bullet() works fine. I'm sure this is an obvious problem but I can't get it to work.

The class:

```java
class balls {

  void ball() {
  fill(ellipseColor);  
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  }

  void bullet() {
    ellipseColor= color(224, 131, 81);
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
    speedX = speedX * -1;
  }

  void newBall() {
    fill(ellipseColor);
    ellipse(newX, newY, 20, 20);

  }
```

The if statement:

```java
if(x > width-5 && (y < mouseY-75 || y > mouseY+ 75)) {
 b_1.bullet();
 b_1.newBall();
}
```

x, y, newX, newY:

```java
x = x + speedX;
y = y + speedY;
newX= newX + newSpeedX;
newY= newY + newSpeedY;
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing your `newBall()` function does is draw a single ellipse for a single frame. That won't do much.

Instead, you need to make a class that encapsulates everything you need to draw a Ball. Keep an `ArrayList` of instances of that class, and add an instance when you want to add a Ball. Then tell the balls to move and draw themselves.

Here's an example:

```java
ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
}

void mouseClicked(){
  balls.add(new Ball(mouseX, mouseY));
}

void draw(){
 background(0);
 for(Ball ball : balls){
   ball.draw();
 }
}

class Ball{
  float x;
  float y;

  public Ball(float x, float y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  void draw(){
    y++;
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  }
}
```